# To do list with js disabled in the browser & no database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, next.js

Pretty much what the title describes. I need to build a todo app for a job interview, but js must be disabled in the browser, and not using a database.

Any js must be done on the server side.
I have a beginner grasp on node/express and know how to serve html files, but I’m  not sure how to go about updating the html with user input without js Dom manipulation. What would be a reasonable approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could send data to the server with the help of forms (so no client side js required) and serve static html pages from the server to the client.